# how to add new column on heroku with postgresql database

Tags: laravel, postgresql, heroku

I deploy my laravel project on heroku and it works perfectly,
but when i am adding new column by trying following command

> heroku run php artisan migrate:refresh

in a specific table by following official documentation it works locally and create problem on heroku

**SQLSTATE[23502]: Not null violation: 7 ERROR:  column "column_name"

contains null values**

on local development i am using mysql database,
on heroku i am using postgresql **Heroku Postgres** add-on

Comment: You don't have the same data locally as you do in the database on heroku. My guess is that your local database is empty (or at the very least this table in particular is empty) whereas the table in the database on heroku does have data. When you add a new column with a `NOT NULL` constraint but without a `DEFAULT VALUE` those rows end up with `column_name -> null`, which violates the constraint.

Comment: ok thanks for your reply and please guide me on how can i set a default value for column

Comment: There's no way to really help without seeing your code. If you're using plain SQL (and not e.g an ORM or a query builder) it should simply be `ALTER TABLE <table> ADD COLUMN <column_name> <type> NOT NULL DEFAULT <default_value>`.

Comment: thanks,i have solved my issue